# SQL: Is there any way to return a row from several querys?

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to know if it's possible and how to return a row from several querys which attack to different tables. I mean, each query returns different fields and no one of them are any key to link with any other query result.

Imagine that you've got three tables, A, B, C and all of them have different fields and all of them have only one row.

A(attrib1, atrrib2)
B(attrib3, attrib4, attrib5)
C(attrib6)

I would like to return only one row with all the data of each table.

The result wouldbe(attrib1, attrib2, attrib3, attrib4, attrib5, attrib6). It doesn't matter the order.

I would like to know if there is any way to do this only with SQL, no programming.

I'm using MySQL. If it's not possible to do this in MySQL is it possible to do it in another database?

Comment: That's a standard `SELECT ... JOIN`. See manual for details: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are describing a `cross join`:

```
select a.*, b.*, c.*
from a cross join b cross join c;
```

This is standard SQL and supported by all databases that support SQL.

Comment: Thanks @Gordon Linoff!!! I don't use join command. I "join" tables through their id's only not using joing command

Comment: @JoséCarlos . . . I have no idea what you are trying to say in your comment.  Your question has no `id`s and this answers the question you have asked here.  If you have a different question, ask a *new* question with appropriate sample data and desired results.  Changing your question will invalidate this answer which could lead to downvotes.

Comment: Sorry @Gordon Linoff!!! I have not explain very well. You're answer is completely right and it helps me a lot!!! I have checked that I can do the same with select * from A, B, C

Comment: The `JOIN` predicates (`INNER JOIN`, `OUTER JOIN`, `CROSS JOIN`) have been the recommended way to join tables since 1989. I respectfully submit that it's time for you (and everyone else still putting join criteria in the WHERE clause) to get with the standard.